# Media Tek WiFi 6 MT7921 Wireless LAN Card disconnects randomly

Tags: drivers, network-adapter, asus-laptop

OS: **Win10**

Laptop **Model: AUS TUF Gaming F15**

BIOS: **BIOS version 310**

Issue: **Media Tek WiFi 6 MT7921** disconnect randomly.

I updated Windows 10 on my ASUS TUF Gaming F15, and after that, the driver Media Tek WiFi 6 MT7921 abruptly disconnected. The frequency of disconnection increased so much that every 2 minutes, I had to hard press the power button for 20 seconds for a driver to appear again in Device Manager.

Things I have done:

1. Hard press the **Power Button for 20 seconds**
2. Changed the property setting of **Network Adapter** > **Power Management**
   [image]
3. Changed the property setting of **Network Adapter**> **Advanced** > **Preferred Band** > 5Ghz
   [image]

4. **Uninstalled MediaTek driver** and restart the Laptop.
5. I tried MyASUS app and I got the following **suggestion**. **But I don't know how to follow these steps.**  What it is trying to say?
   [image]
6. I have followed the steps suggested on this 2nd [anwers[dot]microsoft[dot]com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/wifi-6-mediatek-mt7921-card-not-working-after-june/1ddd16e9-8690-43a8-a64b-ef97d9d30a7e) but this doesn't work as well. The one which says the following,

The Asus employee made me reset the bios setting and after that, my wifi worked again.

For BIOS version 310 ONLY (i don't know if it's working for other version)

1 - after full booting (and you see the desktop), press the power button for the 20s (wait for the 20s even if you have a black screen like the PC is shutdown)

2 - press the power button to boot and press F2 until you get to the BIOS.

3 - Press F9 and answer YES to get the default setting

4 - Press F10 and answer YES to save and restart.

5 - The PC will reboot by itself and after that WI-FI will be back

**Can anyone help me to sort out the issue?** It is a frustrating experience and disturbs my day-to-day life as I mainly work on the computer.

Comment: @John how will this help? Can you elaborate?

Comment: What is the 80211ax/ac/n configured to?